# .NET MVC - pass List of runtime type to Grid<T>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have `List<MyType> list` and need to pass list to `@Html.Grid((IEnumerable<MyType>)list, "MvcGrid/customGridView")` in my view. MyType was created at runtime. **Can you provide some example code to do this??**

---

Concreatelly:
In my controller i have this code:

```
public ActionResult dataRuntime()
{
            var myType = CompileResultType();
            var myObject = Activator.CreateInstance(myType);
            var myObject2 = Activator.CreateInstance(myType);

            Type listType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(new Type[] { myObject.GetType() });
            IList listt = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(listType);
            listt.Add(myObject);
            listt.Add(myObject2);

            ViewData["type"] = myType;

            return View(list);
}
```

So I have `List<MyType>` with two MyType objects. In view I have:

```
@{
    Type t = (Type)ViewData["type"];
    var list = Model;
}
```

and need to call method like this:

```
@Html.Grid((IEnumerable<MyType>)list, "MvcGrid/customGridView")
```

So I need to do something like:

```
@Html.Grid((IEnumerable<t>)list, "MvcGrid/customGridView")
```

but it doesn't work, obviously.
So I tried do this:

```
@{
    // For non-public methods, you'll need to specify binding flags too
    System.Reflection.MethodInfo method = Html.GetType().GetMethod("Grid")
                                 .MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { t });
    var g = method.Invoke(Html, new object[] { list, "MvcGrid/customGridView" });
}
```

but I get an error:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object

which is logic, because HtmlHelper doesn't have method Grid.

Grid class is defined here:
https://github.com/leniel/Grid.Mvc/blob/master/GridMvc/Grid.cs

Do someone know, how to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Grid` is actually static method, so you do not pass Html as the first parameter to `method.Invoke`.

In case of static method, `Invoke` ignores the first parameter, so you can pass in just `null` for example. Do not forget to put `Html` into the parameters array:

```
method.Invoke(null, new object[] { Html, list, "MvcGrid/customGridView" });
```

Edit: and also you do not get the reference to `Grid` method from `HtmlHelper` type. Use intellisense to find out on which type is the `Grid` method defined and use that type instead of `Html.GetType()`

Comment: Thanks. This code works brilliant: var method = typeof(GridMvc.Html.GridExtensions).GetMethods().Where(mi => mi.Name == "Grid").ElementAt(0).MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { t }); var g = method.Invoke(null, new object[] { Html, list });